# Error “There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.” even after updating to SP3 on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, memory

We are getting this error :

`“There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.”` everyday, and the error lasts for about a minute, after that the queries are executed normally with no error.

At first we assumed this was a bug in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 10.52.4000.0 according to the [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/982854/fix-error-there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-interna) , and updated to Service pack 3, but the error still continues.
We use the Express edition, and are aware that there is a limit on the ram that SQL server instance can use to run queries. According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms143685(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
The table here shows the limit on SQL Server Express as 1 GB.
On analysing the perfmon logs, the counter

> MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS:Memory Manager\Total Server Memory (KB) had value
> 1443840 KB

and

> MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS:Memory Manager\Target Server Memory (KB) had value
> 1443840 KB

We assume this is how high the SQL Server Express Editions can consume.
Also this was the Memory Consumption report that was taken after we had encountered the problem. Here we see that Stolen Pages are too high, tried searching regarding this and came up with the result that high stolen page value can cause Memory pressure.
[image]

[image]

1. Could this High Stolen page value be a reason for the error that we encounter?
2. The reason these Stolen pages being this high, are they not freed automatically?
3. How to Free these Stolen pages ?
4. What other possible reasons can cause this error?

Comment: What is the value you have set in max memory setting?

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin the default value 2147483647 MB

Comment: [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117001/db-engine-stolen-server-memory-is-too-high) may help. In short, queries requiring a large sort or hash operation may be the cause. Additional query/index tuning may be needed to live within SQL Express memory limits.

Comment: Look at the query that is running when you have that error. You may want to tune this specific query so that it doesn't use that much RAM (for sorting or hash for example). I guess I would also set the max memory to 1 Gb... just to make it clean...