# Do stolen pages (as in sys.dm_os_performance_counters) report anything that sys.dm_os_memory_clerks does not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory, dmv, buffer-pool

I have been under the misconception that `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name LIKE 'Stolen Server Memory%';` shows how much memory the OS is stealing from SQL Server. The truth, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-memory-manager-object?view=sql-server-ver16#memory-manager-counters), is

> Specifies the amount of memory the server is using for purposes other than database pages.

which I take to mean "the amount of memory used by SQL Server (i.e. not the OS) for anything other than the buffer pool".

With this in mind, is there any point in checking `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` if I am already checking `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks ORDER BY pages_kb DESC`? Given that the buffer pool is always at the top of that list (your server is doomed if it isn't), determining how much memory isn't being used by it should be a simple matter of arithmetic.

I suspect that I am wrong about this because these two numbers do not match on my server. However, I do not know how to find out why.

```sql
-- Total stolen memory.
SELECT top (1) cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name LIKE 'Stolen Server Memory%'
ORDER BY cntr_value desc;

-- Total memory not in buffer pool.
-- Should be the same as the above but is always less on my machine.
SELECT SUM(pages_kb)
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
WHERE [Type] <> 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL';
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252612/sql-server-stolen-server-memory-what-it-consists-of
Plan cache isn't considered as part of stolen memory.

Comment: @DavidWiseman That looks like a large part of an answer. Feel free to submit it as one.

Comment: @DavidWiseman The bounty expires soon. Might as well take a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen memory isn't just all memory except for what's in the buffer pool.  Notably, the plan cache wouldn't be counted as stolen memory.

There is a [similar question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252612/sql-server-stolen-server-memory-what-it-consists-of) with an explanation of what stolen memory includes.  This also links to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117001/db-engine-stolen-server-memory-is-too-high).

The official documentation seems to be light on details about stolen memory and what it includes.  This explanation comes from an [old support article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402043812/http://support.microsoft.com:80/en-us/kb/271624).

> Stolen. Total number of buffers that are stolen from the buffer pool by the five memory managers (General, Query Plan, Optimizer, Utilities, Connection). These pages are used to service memory allocations that are smaller than 8 KB.

Stolen memory can be useful to monitor - it can highlight that your buffer pool was constrained which could provide an explanation for some performance issues.  If you also monitor sys.dm_os_memory_clerks, you should be able to work out exactly where the memory went.
*e.g.  A large amount of memory used by MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIONS indicates that the memory is been used by memory grants.*

*[DBA Dash](https://dbadash.com/), a free, open-source monitoring tool I created, tracks performance counters including stolen pages. It also keeps a historical record of sys.dm_os_memory_clerks. This allows you to go back in time and diagnose memory related performance issues.*